# How can I use Vuex modules state without nested objects?

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I'm trying to convert existing Vuex state to modules. I'm trying to use modules like this:

```
const moduleA = {
  state: {},

mutations: {
  update (state, payload) { // payload is an object
  state = payload // doesn't work
  }
},
```

I'm registering modules:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    a: moduleA,
    b: moduleB
  }
})
```

The question is: is it possible to use state without nesting as I'm trying to do? Or the only way is to have something like:

```
const moduleA = {
  state: {
   one: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    update (state, payload) {
      state.one = payload // it works
    },
  },
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to have the same structure as it was before and being able to get the state as `state.a` instead of `state.a.one`

Thank you

Comment: If you replace the complete state you will loose Vue reactivity. Instead of `state = payload` have you tried using `Object.assign(state, payload)`?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am facing this right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can -- just refactor the modules into separate files and then use an index file to bring them all together:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import users from './store.users.js'
import entries from './store.entries.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    users,
    entries
  }
})

export default store
```

Then in each module's file (e.g. `store.entries.js`, you can follow the pattern you're familiar with, but with `namespaced` set to true:

```
const module = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {},
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
}

module.actions.update = ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
  // commit, state, etc refer to the local store
}

export default module
```

For files using the store, you can import the index and then call by module:

```
import store from '../stores/store.index.js'

// ...

store.dispatch('entries/update', payload)
```

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand my question. I already use separate files etc. My question is: can I don't wrap state inside the module in the object? I mean: in old version without modules I had `state = { users: [] }`. Can I make state in the module not as an object but as an array for example? For being able to use the same structure instead of nested objects(in case I use object in the module `state = { users: [] }` path to my users array will be state.users.users instead of state.users)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `state = Object.assign(state, payload)`. But note that this means you keep all existing props and shallow merge new ones in.

You cannot create a new state object unless you lift the logic up to the global namespace and use [dynamic module registration](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration)